# Libgdx make getStatuscode called once only in update()

Tags: libgdx

I'm developing an app but when I try to getstatuscode of httprequest 
in order to know Which of the gameend overlay to call the status code is called multiple times so how do I call it just once

```
public void update(float dt) {

    for (NewPhysicsActor baseEnemyOthers: balloonList) {

        if (baseEnemyOthers.getY() < 250) {
            removeList.add(baseEnemyOthers);
            gameFailed();
        }
    }
}

public void gameFailed() {

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET);
    request.setUrl("https://www.google.com");
    Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(request, new HttpResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void handleHttpResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) {
            HttpStatus status = httpResponse.getStatus();
            if (status.getStatusCode() >= 200 && status.getStatusCode() < 300) {

                togglePaused();
                watchVideoOverlay.setVisible(isPaused());

            } else {
                togglePaused();
                levelFailedOverlay.setVisible(isPaused());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {
            togglePaused();
            levelFailedOverlay.setVisible(isPaused());
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            togglePaused();
            levelFailedOverlay.setVisible(isPaused());
        }

    });

}
```

if I off my data connection everything works perfectly
 but when it's on the problem continues. Watchoverlay() is called on and off continuously without stop

Comment: Can you add more info your question is a little unclear. What is called twice? The http response?

Comment: This part is the issue.  It's being repeatedly called    if (status.getStatusCode() >= 200 && status.getStatusCode() < 300) {

                togglePaused();
                watchVideoOverlay.setVisible(isPaused());

            }